# File transfer rate to USB stick is totally variable

Tags: usb, lubuntu, rsync

I just rebuild my old desktop, which is now running Lubuntu 15.04, and tried to transfer a 1.3GB file into my 8GB thumb drive. I was immediately reminded of a problem that has plagued me for a long time.

If I use PCManFM the transfer starts at about 68% complete and slowly (and I mean *slowly*) gets up to 100%. So the progress bar is barely even a suggestion.

I then used rsync (with the progress argument) to see what was going on. A similar thing happened. The data transfer started off at about 4MB per second and then crawled down to 1MB per second. And it took about the same amount of time.

The transfer will eventually complete but I was curious as to why this might be happening? Is there any way to get the progress to be a bit more accurate?

Comment: This could get a little complicated depending on exactly whay your hardware is. Some tools you may want to consider for this is iotop to see if the speed that you are reading from your main disk storage to the flash drive. Also caching does speed this up but will make it get slower once you get out of the cache. This wikipedia page explains https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing) if the disk has a write cache for ssd. To provide a more useful answer I will need to know if the internal disk on your desktop is a spining hard disk or solid state drive. Caching is probalby the answer.

Comment: Does the issue occur with other USB thumb drives, or just this one?

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys. Spaced on this one.  @ianorlin - It's an HHD, pretty sure 5200 RPM. After reading that article, caching is most likely the answer.

Comment: @drkokandy - It seems to occur with every thumb drive.